# Is it possible to join the Google One-tap sign in beta test programme?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

Got Google One-tap sign in working locally, however, on testing on our staging server I'm getting the error 'The client origin is not permitted to use this API' in the console.

Looking at the [Troubleshooting docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/troubleshooting), I can see that this is probably because we are not whitelisted for the beta test programme.

Does anyone know if it is possible to join the beta programme at the current time? If not, does anyone know how long it will be before there will be any updates?

Comment: *The beta test program for this API is currently closed. We are improving the API's cross-browser functionality and will provide updates here in the coming months.*

Comment: Was searching for the same, I had an old key for which it's working fine locally but not with the new keys. Can you tell me when exactly did you generated your OAuth Key?

Comment: is there an update when this will be available?

Comment: When will this be available?

Comment: Aliexpress is the one user in beta test right?

Comment: vrbo.com is in the beta - it's killing me, because my customers are begging for this.